# Does Stringers interface only work with value receiver in golang

Tags: go

All:

Just one quick question:

In Tour of Go tutorial

https://tour.golang.org/methods/18

I tried to implement that `String()` method as

```
func (ip *IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
}
```

I used a pointer receiver but when it does not work in `main()`

```
for n, a := range addrs {
    fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", n, a)
}
```

still show `[127, 0, 0, 1]`

It only works when I change it to value receiver like:

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
}
```

Does it mean fmt only looking for value receiver version of `String()` or did I miss something for my implementation?

Thanks

Comment: Is `addrs` a slice of pointers or values?

Comment: @Adrian You can click into the link I provide. It is a map[string]IPAddr

Comment: If code is relevant, it should be included in the body of your question, not at an external link. The reason it only works with a value receiver is because you're using a value type. If you were passing a pointer type, it would work with the pointer receiver.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks, get it. Just one quick question following this: since I can not define both pointer receiver and value receiver versions at same time( throws redeclare error), how can I predict which type of that receiver will be used by others?

Comment: Be consistent and one or the other becomes canonical. Notice in the standard library that any given type is pretty much *always* used either as a value or as a pointer, never a mix of the two. The constructor func, if there is one, returns the canonical type; all the methods have receivers of the canonical type; all functions taking or returning it use the canonical type. Anyone using the non-canonical type should be expected to know what they're doing.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks, got it.

Answer (score -3):

> Does Stringers interface only work with value receiver in golang ?

No.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell why the pointer receiver version does not work in this example?

Comment: Yes. If you show your buggy code.

Comment: Thanks, I figure it out. It is just because I did not pass the right type